# How do I change the space between words in Word 2010?

Tags: microsoft-word

I want to create a style that makes the selected text have something similar to margin/padding in CSS, but in the horizontal axis only. Example:

> Normal text normal text       New Style       normal text

Comment: +1 for an interesting questino. Unfortunately, however, I think that this cannot be done /in any reasonably simple way/.

Comment: See my response below. There's a relatively simple workaround.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, since word isn't a full-blown desktop publishing software, it doesn't provide an easy option to modify word spacing. However, you can simulate this property with a quick workaround:

1. Select the empty space that you want to expand.
2. Click the square button in the lower-right corner of Font section of Home tab in the Ribbon.
3. Go to Character Spacing tab.
4. Set Spacing to Expanded and play with the number to the right of it.

You might have to do this a few times until you get the desired amount of empty space because there is no live preview available.

Comment: nice, actually I am looking for a style

Comment: Style will let you expand spacing only by the fixed amount as configured into it. If you ever need to increase/decrease that space, you'll have to go back to this dialogue. Also the style will have to be applied to space characters only as it will increase spacing between ***all*** selected characters.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this and it works.

1. Select the document you wish to include additional spaces between text
2. Use the Search button shortcut ( CTRL + H ).
3. In the find section type " " (i.e. one space character)
4. In the replace section type the number of spaces you wish to include
5. Click on the Replace All button

You shall have you document with the extended number of spaces you desire between words.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to read the question rather than the title.  It is about padding around specific words, not all spacing between words.

Answer (score 0):

Highlight the space you want to enlarge. Access the font style and try various fonts. Typically "CONSOLAS" and "chi-boot" have particularly wide spaces between words, the alphabet of your text will remain unchanged.
Once you have done one space to your satisfaction, others  can be done by simply copy and paste of the first. - Since it is a single space, albeit by an alternative font, this method even fools the spell checker.
I've used this method in Headings, never in a whole document, but it MAY even work with the "Search & Replace" function, in lieu Copy & Paste.

Answer (score -1):

Spaces between words are controlled by the font.  You'll need a font that supports double the space between works.